# Autofac overrides last registration for generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

I am trying to register the generic type with Autofac, but the last value ends up overriding the previous value. The common project has entity service interface,

```
public interface IEntityService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    TEntity GetByID(object id);
}
```

The implementation classes, Project A

```
public class EntityService<TEntity> : Common.IEntityService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected IContext _iContext;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _iDbSet;

    public EntityService(IContext context)
    {
        _iContext = context;
        _iDbSet = IContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return IDbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

Implementation class project B

```
public class EntityService<TEntity> : Common.IEntityService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected ILogDbContext  _iLogDbContext;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _iDbSet;

    public EntityService(ILogDbContext context)
    {
        _iLogDbContext = context;
        _iDbSet = IContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return _iDbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

Registration in web.api

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new EFModule());
var container = builder.Build();
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

The EFModule class

```
public class EFModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
      builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service.EntityService<>))
      .As(typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
      .Named(Common.ConfigType.ProjectType.Main,typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
      .InstancePerDependency();

      builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LogProject.Service.EntityService<>))
      .As(typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
      .Named(Common.ConfigType.ProjectType.Log, typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
      .InstancePerDependency();
   }
}
```

What is happening is, all works fine for whatever configuration is in the last. Say, I put the

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LogProject.Service.EntityService<>))
```

and in web.config, the project type is `LogProject`. Then it works fine, but if I put `MainProject` in the config file. Same is happening the other way around, whatever line is in the last (`Main` or `Log`), in the `module` if that is not the same in `web.config` it overrides throws an exception. Basically, the generics are not resolving based on but, but are getting overridden by the last value.

Answer (score 1):

You are registering 2 instances of `typeof(Common.IEntityService<>)`. It is normal and expected behavior that the last registered instance wins.

Per [the documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#default-registrations):

> If more than one component exposes the same service, **Autofac will use the last registered component as the default provider of that service**

If you want Autofac to be able to differentiate between the two, you have a couple of options:

### Create Separate Abstractions

```
public interface ILogEntityService<TEntity> : IEntityService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
}
```

Use the above interface for your Log project's constructor parameters, and register it like:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service.EntityService<>))
  .As(typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
  .Named(Common.ConfigType.ProjectType.Main,typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
  .InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LogProject.Service.EntityService<>))
  .As(typeof(ILogEntityService<>))
  .Named(Common.ConfigType.ProjectType.Log, typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
  .InstancePerDependency();
```

### Use Concrete Types/AsSelf

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Service.EntityService<>))
  .AsSelf()
  .Named(Common.ConfigType.ProjectType.Main,typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
  .InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(LogProject.Service.EntityService<>))
  .AsSelf()
  .Named(Common.ConfigType.ProjectType.Log, typeof(Common.IEntityService<>))
  .InstancePerDependency();
```

Then use the concrete type in the service constructors

```
public SomeService(ConcreteEntityService<SomeClass> foo)
```

Of course, using the first option is better in terms of being able to swap/mock implementations.